# How to get IK response for user provided pose in MoveIt(Baxter)

Tags: inverse-kinematics, moveit, baxter, rosservice, arm-kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Below is the code snippet of ik_service_client.py provided for Baxter SDK

```
rospy.init_node("rsdk_ik_service_client")
ns = "ExternalTools/" + limb + "/PositionKinematicsNode/IKService"
iksvc = rospy.ServiceProxy(ns, SolvePositionIK)
ikreq = SolvePositionIKRequest()
hdr = Header(stamp=rospy.Time.now(), frame_id='base')
poses = {
    'left': PoseStamped(
        header=hdr,
        pose=Pose(
            position=Point(
                x=0.657579481614,
                y=0.851981417433,
                z=0.0388352386502,
            ),
            orientation=Quaternion(
                x=-0.366894936773,
                y=0.885980397775,
                z=0.108155782462,
                w=0.262162481772,
            ),
        ),
    ),
   
}

ikreq.pose_stamp.append(poses[limb])
try:
    rospy.wait_for_service(ns, 5.0)
    resp = iksvc(ikreq)
except (rospy.ServiceException, rospy.ROSException), e:
    rospy.logerr("Service call failed: %s" % (e,))
    return 1
resp_seeds = struct.unpack('<%dB' % len(resp.result_type),
                           resp.result_type)


if (resp_seeds[0] != resp.RESULT_INVALID):
    seed_str = {
                ikreq.SEED_USER: 'User Provided Seed',
                ikreq.SEED_CURRENT: 'Current Joint Angles',
                ikreq.SEED_NS_MAP: 'Nullspace Setpoints',
               }.get(resp_seeds[0], 'None')
```

Whenever I get results, it is always form the `ikreq.SEED_CURRENT"'Current JointAngles'`. How can I retreieve the ikreq result form the user provided input?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274616/how-to-get-ik-response-for-user-provided-pose-in-moveit(baxter)/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The SDK has a [pretty thorough walkthrough](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/IK_Service_-_Code_Walkthrough) of retrieving exactly what you are looking for. The "result" you are referring to is specifically because of this line

```
resp_seeds = struct.unpack('<%dB' % len(resp.result_type),
                       resp.result_type)
```

Where you are only looking at what seeding methods were used in the original IK request. What you want to be looking at is the `resp.joints` field. Here is the [complete service definition](https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/baxter_common/blob/master/baxter_core_msgs/srv/SolvePositionIK.srv) including comments on what all of the fields are, and here is the relevant snippet from the previously-linked walkthrough:

```
if (resp.isValid[0]):
    print("SUCCESS - Valid Joint Solution Found:")
    # Format solution into Limb API-compatible dictionary
    limb_joints = dict(zip(resp.joints[0].name, resp.joints[0].position))
    print limb_joints
else:
    print("INVALID POSE - No Valid Joint Solution Found.")

return 0
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1